# Which one is the longest anime ever created and how long is it hourwise?

Tags: anime-production

Which one is the longest anime ever created?

Not just episodes, the duration of each episode is also important.

Comment: Mine digs deeper. It's no just episodes, but duration as well. Therefore, the answer could be another anime.

Comment: was about to do the same as @AkiTanaka though i would add that the answer there is 30-minute running episodes so doing your math it also is the longest in terms of duration

Comment: I won't click the "that solved my problem buttom" in case someone has a more thorough asnwer. I have the feeling that if I click it I won't get any more answers...